# React native / Flatlist with Switches : they switch back immediately

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm pretty new to React, trying to do something (I thought) simple, a list of parameters with switches.

But when I switch them, they immediately switch back to original display. I saw some posts around that, but couldn't solve the problem.

I also tried to put the Switch value in a state, but then I get the "hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" error.

Here is the code :

```
    const UserPlantsPrefs = ({userPlantsPrefs}) => {
    
        const [prefs, setPrefs] = useState([
            {
                "plant": "plant one",
                "hasPref": true
            },
            {
                "plant": "plant two",
                "hasPref": true
            }
        ]);
    
        function toggleSwitch(value, index) {
            setPrefs((prevPrefs) => {
                prevPrefs[index].hasPref = value;
                return prevPrefs;
            })
        }
    
        function PrefItem({item, index}) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text>{item.plant}</Text>
                    <Switch
                        onValueChange={(value) => {
                            toggleSwitch(value, index);
                        }}
                        value={item.hasPref}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
    
        return (
            <View style={{backgroundColor: "white"}}>
                <FlatList data={prefs} renderItem={PrefItem}/>
            </View>
        )
    }
    
    export default UserPlantsPrefs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `setPrefs` inside `toggleSwitch` returns the same object is is given after modifying it in-place.

If the result of a `setState` call is `==` equal to its previous value, React will not re-render, so in order to cause a re-render, you need to create a *new* object.

Here would be one way of creating a *new* object with the value you want:

```js
setPrefs((prevPrefs) => {
  return {
    ...prevPrefs,
    [index]: {
      ...prevPrefs[index],
      hasPref: value
    }
  }
})
```

(This snippet uses [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [computed-property initialisers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015), which you may want to look up - or you can use any other way of shallow-cloning the object to create a new one)

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks !